# Using COUNTIFS to count and also exclude multiple texts in a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I’d like to start by giving due credit to @skkakkar who helped me with a similar problem and offered some useful suggestions.

What I’m trying to do is use the COUNTIFS function with the help of a criteria table, to count how many times Company3 E$:6$ occurs in A$:A$, then count how many times Full Time – Perm F$6$ occurs in B$:B$, then count all cells with text in C$:C$ but exclude all the ones that start with “Factory” and return a value.

In the Attempt Table I tried to use the formula =COUNTIFS($A:$A,$E$6,$B:$B,$F$6,$C:$C,$G$6) which returns 6, because excel does not recognize “Factory” on its own.

But when I input the full string “Factory - Tampa” in the formula =COUNTIFS($A:$A,$E$7,$B:$B,$F$7,$C:$C,$G$7), excel returns 5 because there are 5 other cells in C$:C$ that do not equal Factory – Tampa (close to what I’m looking for, but not quite).

The problem is that the cells in C$:C$ that I want to exclude contain Factory - Tampa, Factory - Phoenix, which is more than 1 word.

In the below screenshot I have given an example of the expected result from the criteria I want to count.

A suggestion was to change all cells that have "Factory - something" to just Factory, but with rows that are 500+ long, that might not be efficient, and I would probably need another formula for that.

Please let me know if you need more clarity. I appreciate your help in advance.

Screen shot of Table:
[image: Screenshot of Table]

Comment: Changing every `factory-` to `factory` is very easy. In column D, `=if(left(c2,7)="Factory","Factory",c2)`

Comment: what is the max number of rows you are dealing with?

Comment: @findwindow and the follow up step to copy values back to C.  However its preferrable to work with information you have _if you can_ rather then destroying something that may be of use later.

Comment: I feel sumproduct opportunity here.  I am going to give it a 10 count though in case scott is already answering

Comment: @ForwardEd or have formula refer to column D but yes, I know your fetish for sumproduct =P

Comment: @findwindow, dont make me go aggregate all over you! 8)

Comment: @ForwardEd I'd prefer if you index/match all over me~

Comment: actually just looking at the data layout, you could even use a dsum here with a little tweaking of the search data that is

Comment: @findwindow changing the factory - to just factory did it for me thanks so much.

Comment: @Forward Ed the number of rows will continue to change as the employees increase or decrease, right now we are ~1000. And yes I referenced column D in the formula for ease thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$23=E2)*($B$2:$B$23=F2)*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C$2:$C$23,G2))))
```

I used the above sumproduct which is ok if you are not using full column references.

Proof of Concept
[image: Proof of Concept]

Personally I am not a fan of having all your criteria you are searching for in one cell.  This is currently creating the caveat that you CANNOT search for Factory.  It would require modifying the formula.  My preferred method would be to have Warehouse, Office  and home as their own cells.  I would have probably layed out each one in their own row and summed the results.  That would have used the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$23=E4)*($B$2:$B$23=F4)*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(G4,$C$2:$C$23))))
```

And then if I wanted to know Factories I would have entered `Factory*` in G4

Proof of Second Concept

[image: Proof of Second Concept]

Comment: I am using full column referencing due to the large number of rows ~1000, please explain why full referencing will not be good for your suggestion so I can get a better understanding.

Comment: @Ben It will slow down excel.

Comment: even though it does not look like an array formula, the part inside the sumproduct is an array calculation.  As a result when using full column references, you can be creating a substantial amount of unnecessary calculation thus slowing down your overall performence...Or what @findwindow said.  So if you know you only have 2000 rows of data to deal with you are better off setting the range to cover rows 1 to 2000 instead of 1 to the very last row excel can deal with.

Comment: @ForwardEd how did it go?

Comment: @ForwardEd this is my formula

Comment: @ForwardEd my formula =SUMPRODUCT(('count May'!$D$2:$D$2000=Categories!$A$5)*('count May'!$E$2:$E$2000=Categories!$B$3)*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH('count May'!$F$2:$F$2000,Categories!$C$4)))) count may is the sheet for the month of may(I'm doing this for a full year), categories is the sheet that has my helper column. When I paste the data from the export with about 1000 rows i.e company, fulltime into my month sheet the cell that has the above formula changes all the cell ranges from $2:$2000 to $1600:$2000. Essentially the pasted data makes the formula start from the cell after the last data. Any idea

Comment: Actually I do not know.  That would be worth posting as a question I think.

Answer (score 0):

Use wildcards:

```
,$G$6 & "*",
```

Comment: Are we bored today?  You have been everywhere.  I am not complaining the answers given are good answers, just curious.

Comment: I am stuck on a coding problem, and I'm here to stop myself from ripping my hair out.

Comment: Mine is repetitive currently as I convert one database to a different one with different tables and schema.

Comment: Sounds like a blast

Answer (score 0):

Do your Countifs like this, you have to specify what you are searching for. For Factory you can just do Factory* as * is a wildcard, so it will look for just the word Factory. So in G6 enter in Factory*

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A, $E6, $B:$B, $F6,$C:$C, $G6)
```

[image]